# UINavigationBar color changes when showing a detail view inside a UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I'm having some trouble understanding what might be a default iOS behavior.

My app container is a `UITabBarController`:

- My tabs contain a `UISplitViewController`, `preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible`;
- The master VC is always embedded in a `UINavigationController`

The issue is:

- When the secondary VC is a `UIViewController`, the master navigation (or tab) bar is fine.
- When the secondary VC is a `UINavigationController`, the master navigation (or tab) bar gets grey.

I have a `translucent` navigation bar with `UIBarStyleBlack`

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: i wonder how the tab bar gets affected by the nav bar!!!

Comment: you have to set the translucent to NO and apply the color as you wish.

Comment: I want my nav bar to be translucent. Here are some pics: http://imgur.com/xjGLXTT,KY0lYQe#1

Comment: i see there is a slight grey at the right of he nav bar. So you dont want that grey right?

Comment: Yes the grey is what I don't want

Comment: Somehow the barTintColor was set to nil, so I set [UIColor clearColor] instead...hope it can help somebody :D